# onClick addClass to the image you click on

Tags: jquery

I have a series of images being pulled onto my page from the database. I need to add some sort of style to it when someone clicks on one. The style will only apply to the image you are currently clicking on, and not the others. The script I have highlights every image you click on. Any ideas how to fix that?

**PHP (When I pull these images)**

```
$war_list .= '
<span name="fighter">
    <label for="'.$value["fighter_id"].'">
        <img src="'.$value["fighter_photo"].'" id="fighter-icon" title="'.$value["fighter_full_name"].'">
    </label> <input type="radio" value="'.$value["fighter_id"].'" id="'.$value["fighter_id"].'" name="list">
</span>';
```

**Jquery**

```
$("span[name=fighter]").click(function() {
    var something = $(this).val();
    $(this).find("img").addClass('red');
    alert(something);   
});
```

In a nut shell I'm trying to do this: when you click on an image it needs to add a class. When you click on another image it will remove the class of the last image clicked and add it to the one you currently have clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mysteryos/2wb2r/) for the answer to your question:
You can simply switch the anchors to your image tags.

**HTML Code:**

```
<span name="fighter">
    <a>Link 1</a>
</span>
<span name="fighter">
    <a>Link 2</a>
</span>
<span name="fighter">
    <a>Link 3</a>
</span>
<span name="fighter">
    <a>Link 4</a>
</span>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var myspan = $("span[name=fighter]").click(function(){
    myspan.find('a').removeClass('red');
    $(this).find('a').first().addClass('red');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
span a{
    color: blue;
}
.red{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    if('img').hasClass('yourclass') {
        $(this).removeClass('yourclass');
    }
    $(this).addClass('yourclass')
})
```

or if you want specific images add a class to each one:

```
 <img class="this_image" src="'.$value["fighter_photo"].'" id="fighter-icon" title="'.$value["fighter_full_name"].'">

$('img.this_image').click(function() {
    if('img.this_image').hasClass('yourclass') {
        $(this).removeClass('yourclass');
    }
    $(this).addClass('yourclass')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("span[name=fighter] img").click(function() {
$("span[name=fighter] img").removeClass('red'); // This removes the existing class
    var something = $(this).parent().parent().val();
    $(this).addClass('red');
    alert(something);   
});
```

Comment: It's still adding the class (and not removing for the last one clicked) to every image I click on.